# perl for loop issue with understanding it

Tags: perl

I'm looking at some old Perl code and I'm trying to figure out what does this statement exaclty mean - I have done programming, but not in Perl. Having a hard time with what this for statement actually means.

```
for ($xx = $x+1 ; $contents[$xx] !~ m/^\:1S\:XXX/  ; $xx++)
```

Is this looping until it finds `:1S:XXX`

If not, then what does this mean?

Can someone help with this?

Thanks

Comment: That's an incomplete statement.

Comment: It stops looping when `$contents[$xx]` is a string that starts with `:1S:XXX`.

Comment: @ikegami I was just trying to understand what this mean: $contents[$xx] !~ m/^\:1S\:XXX/

Comment: @Dave123 `$contents[$xx]` is an array element from the array `@contents`. `$xx` is the iterator in the for loop. `!~` is a negated binding operator used for pattern matches, and `m/.../` is a pattern match. So yes, the loop will continue while that array element does not match the pattern.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be more clear:

```
$xx = $x+1;
$xx++ until substr($contents[$xx], 0, 7) eq ':1S:XXX';
```

However both this and your `for` loops forever if `:1S:XXX` isn't found. So I would consider this which leaves $xx not defined if the searched string isn't found at the beginning of an array element at or after the starting point in $x+1.

```
use List::Util 'first';
my $xx = first { $contents[$_] =~ /^:1S:XXX/ } $x+1 .. @contents-1;
```

In perl regexes `:` can have `\` in front but don't need it.